# Reporting what is seen about the maximum place of a function

Tags: reference-request, terminology

I have plotted the $\sin$ function from $0$ to $5 \pi$. My problem is related to the report of what I see about the plot. I mean I don't know whether my reporting structure is correct or not!?

[image]
Report:
As the plot shows, the function reaches its maxima three times in a $\frac 5 2$ period.

$t=\frac {(2n+1) \pi} 2$ represent**s** the place**s** of maximum**s**.

Or:

$t=(2n+1)\pi/2$ represent the place of maximum**s**.

Can any help me to know which of the sentences is correct? Also, what is the better explanation instead of the $\frac 5 2$ period?!

Comment: Maxima and minima are the plurals of maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is a single thing.  The plural of maximum is maxima.  There are multiple places of maxima.  So the proper sentence is:  "$t=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ represents the places of maxima".  "represets" is singular, "places" and "maxima" plural.

Better explanation of period of 5/2?  The period isn't 5/2.  There were 5/2 periods.  I would say "the function reaches its maxima three times over 5/2 periods".  Or any of  "from 0 to 5π" or "during 2 1/2 periods of 2π" or even "maxima occur once in the first have of each period or a total or 3 times in this graph of 2 1/2 periods" or any variation.  (I personally prefer 2 1/2 over 5/2 for enumerated ordinals but that's an aesthetic value.)

Comment: besides so much thanks for your guidance, can you tell me if the x axes be "time" can we say "the places of maxima". or is it better to say:"the times of maxima"?

Comment: *if* the x axis *is* time, I don't see why not.  These are style questions.